# Software with tabulated notation

Tags: notation

I am looking for a software that allows tabulated notation.

Example:

[image]

Is there any software that allows notation in this way? I would prefer desktop application software.

In ChessBase I can't find an option that allows you to view the notation in this way, but if it is possible or there is a version that allows it, tell me which version.

Comment: Which softwares have you tried?

Comment: I have tried a lot of chess software, chessbase, fritz, arena... and I have not found variety when it comes to presenting the variants, I would like to find tabulated notation option

Comment: By "allows", do you mean as input, as output, as working/editable document, or...?

Comment: I mean notation display options for variants (when studying a lot of possibilities of variants)

Answer (score 3):

Not quite on point, but here are three suggestions

1. Something somewhat similar can be used online, so you might want to get in touch with admin(at)chesstree.net or simply use their site, which is [found here](http://www.chesstree.net/). (May well be that admin also has developed a parser and sends you a copy of it for displaying the trees in text format.)
2. The website [studyopenings](https://studyopenings.com) offers a tabulated view of imported pgn-files, as well as exporting them, however the tabulated displaying isn't persistent.
3. Lastly, on [tailuges github](https://tailuge.github.io/chess-o-tron/public/openings/openingtree.html) you'll find another option that is slightly off of what you ask for, but again getting in touch with its author may turn out to be most helpful.

Good luck in your games!

Comment: It does not allow to show different variants...

Comment: I see. Well, http://www.studyopenings.com/ does, and https://tailuge.github.io/chess-o-tron/public/openings/openingtree.html as well, but both aren't desktop wares; so, the idea of getting in touch with the devs is still a good one I'd say.

Comment: I like the build and study modes of studyopenings.com thanks

Comment: Edited my answer. Your welcome